# Clear Cookies when a user click the OOTB Sign Out from ribbon

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, cookie

I want to clear cookies when a user Sign-out from the SharePoint website.

I have written below code in the Sign Out page which resides in the Layouts folder.

```
deletecookie("CookieName");

function deletecookie(name) {
  document.cookie = name +'=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
```

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server
>   extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\signout.aspx

But this approach didn't work.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\signout.aspx, modify function _spBodyOnLoad(), and add code below to clear cookie before window.close():

```
private void RemoveCookiesAndSignOut()
{
    // Clear session state. 
    if (Context.Session != null)
    {
        Context.Session.Clear();
    }

    string cookieValue = string.Empty;
    if (Context.Request.Browser["supportsEmptyStringInCookieValue"] == "false")
        cookieValue = "NoCookie";

    // Clear my own cookie.
    HttpCookie cookieWinSignIn = Context.Request.Cookies["Morpheus_WindowsSignedIn"];
    if (cookieWinSignIn != null)
    {
        cookieWinSignIn.Value = cookieValue;
        Context.Response.Cookies.Remove("Morpheus_WindowsSignedIn");
        Context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookieWinSignIn);
    }

    // Remove cookies for authentication. 
    HttpCookie cookieSession = Context.Request.Cookies["WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated"];
    if (cookieSession != null)
    {
        cookieSession.Value = cookieValue;
        Context.Response.Cookies.Remove("WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated");
        Context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookieSession);
    }

    HttpCookie cookiePersist = Context.Request.Cookies["MSOWebPartPage_AnonymousAccessCookie"];
    if (cookiePersist != null)
    {
        cookiePersist.Value = cookieValue;
        cookiePersist.Expires = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        Context.Response.Cookies.Remove("MSOWebPartPage_AnonymousAccessCookie");
        Context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookiePersist);
    }

    // Sign out.
    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut();
}
```

Reference: [Sharepoint 2013 - Clear cookie on sign out](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/832677bd-8efc-4ca0-a841-612a4adeaaed/sharepoint-2013-clear-cookie-on-sign-out?forum=sharepointgeneral)